# How to free the memory of Task& a=*new(task::allocate_root()) P2MainTask(&Improve)?

Tags: c++

I originally built my TBB code on Windows and it worked fine. Today I moved my code to Linux system (OpenSUSE 64 bit).

When I tried to run it, the program always stopped after some iterations. I wonder whether it is because the system run out of memory.The part of code is put below.

```
SolverP2 Improve(&inst,&mysolution,StartSolT1,&P1Queue,&P2Queue,&P3Queue,iterControl,exchangeControl,&stopControl );
        task_list tl;  
    P2MainTask& a=*new(task::allocate_root()) P2MainTask(&Improve);
     tl.push_back(a);
        SolverP2T2 Thread2(&inst,&mysolution,StartSolT2,&P1Queue,&P2Queue,iterControl,exchangeControl,&stopControl );
    P2Thread2Task& b=*new(task::allocate_root()) P2Thread2Task(&Thread2);
       tl.push_back(b);
    SolverP2T3 Thread3(&inst,&mysolution,StartSolT3,&P1Queue,&P3Queue,iterControl,exchangeControl,&stopControl );
    P2Thread3Task& c=*new(task::allocate_root()) P2Thread3Task(&Thread3);
      tl.push_back(c);
       Shaking shakeSol(&inst,&mysolution,StartSolT4,&P4Queue,&stopControl );
       ShakingTask& d=*new(task::allocate_root()) ShakingTask(&shakeSol);
       tl.push_back(d);
        cout<<"task deine finished"<<endl;       
       task::spawn_root_and_wait(tl);
         cout<<"task start finished"<<endl;
```

Could anyone tell me how to solve this problem? how can we release the memory defined by new for reuse? Thanks!

Comment: My eyes! Seriously though, for this code you should use pointers with smart pointers instead of references

Comment: The tasks are allocated using the TBB allocator. They are deleted by TBB when the task completes. The only exception is when you don't execute the task. https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/index.htm#reference/task_scheduler/synchronization_task.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the `delete` operator to clean up memory that's no longer being used, but you'll also have to declare some pointer variables since you didn't keep the original pointers:

```
P2MainTask *pa = &a;
delete *pa;
P2Thread2Task *pb = &b;
delete *pb;
P2Thread3Task *pc = &c;
delete *pc;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But should we use delete operator after tasks finished? Besides,can we just use delete a?

Comment: You would have to use the `delete` overload that matches the `new` use to allocate the object. Anyway, don't, because TBB deletes it.